# How do I perform a squash while creating a new branch in git?

Tags: git, version-control

Is there any way I can squash all the previous commit before creating a new branch. I want a clean commit page in bitbucket so that everything on the master branch before the creation of the new branch shows as only 1 commit.

I know the other options of squash while merging a branch or while pushing a branch. I found another answer in stackoverflow which tells how to squash your commit before pushing by using "git rebase -i", but I was looking for an option to squash the commits in the new branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the description of the --orphan option in the git-checkout man page.:

```
--orphan <new_branch>
       Create a new orphan branch, named <new_branch>, started from
       <start_point> and switch to it. The first commit made on this new
       branch will have no parents and it will be the root of a new
       history totally disconnected from all the other branches and
       commits.
```

That seems like what you're trying to do, here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, this will do for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the new branch where you are and then do your `rebase -i` and you will end up with your old branch untouched and your new branch squashed:

```
git checkout -b my_new_branch
git rebase -i
```

When you create your new branch, checkout it or not depending on which branch you want to squash, the new or the old one...

You must understand that git always create new commits, so when you use `rebase -i` to squash, git just create a new commit with all the content of the commits squashed. The old ones are no more visible because not "handled" by a reference. The fact that you keep a reference (the old branch), makes that you still see them.